# Como consultar en un ArrayList diferenciando clases en Java

Tags: java, arraylist, clase

Digamos que yo introduzco de esta manera en un arraylist los datos, por una parte los jugadores y por otra los entrenadores (perteneciente a diferentes clases).

```
public class clsGestor {


    ArrayList<clsPersonasClub> lista;

public clsGestor() {
    lista = new ArrayList<clsPersonasClub>();
}


public ArrayList introducirJugadores() {
    clsJugadores objJugadores = new clsJugadores(clsUtilidadesLP.leerCadena(), clsUtilidadesLP.leerCadena(), clsUtilidadesLP.leerEntero(), clsUtilidadesLP.leerCadena());
    ArrayList lista = this.lista;
    lista.add(objJugadores);
    return lista;
}

public ArrayList introducirEntrenadores() {
    clsEntrenadores objEntrenadores = new clsEntrenadores(clsUtilidadesLP.leerCadena(), clsUtilidadesLP.leerCadena(), clsUtilidadesLP.leerEntero(), clsUtilidadesLP.leerCadena());
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(objEntrenadores);
    return lista;

}
```

Al realizar la consulta yo quiero que solo me saque o los jugadores, o los entrenadores, no los dos, por lo tanto el foreach como tal no me sirve (os dejo como lo tengo):

```
public void consultarJugadores() {
    for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {   
        System.out.println(lista.get(x));
    }                                                                 
//no se sabe cual es la que mas conviene.
}

public void consultarEntrenadores() {
    for (clsPersonasClub mister: lista          
    ) {
        System.out.println(mister);
    }
}
```

¿Sería necesario que cree diferentes ArrayList?

Comment: Para el ArrayList todo van a ser clsPersonasClub (que debería empezar Con mayúsculas por normas de estilo) por lo que no puede diferenciar. O te creas 2 ArrayList (que se deberián encapsular en List) o te recorres toda la lista comprobando en cada uno el tipo que es.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer algo similar a:

```
public interface PersonaFiltrable{

    TipoPersona getTipo();
}

public enum TipoPersona{
    ENTRENADOR,
    JUGADOR;
}

public class Entrenador implements PersonaFiltrable{
    //Tu código actual
    @Override
    public TipoPersona getTipo(){
        return TipoPersona.ENTRENADOR;
    }
}

public class Jugador implements PersonaFiltrable{
    //Tu código actual
    @Override
    public TipoPersona getTipo(){
        return TipoPersona.JUGADOR;
    }
}
```

y para mostrar todo:

```
List<PersonaFiltrable> personas = new ArrayList<>();
personas.add(new Jugador("jugador1"));
personas.add(new Jugador("jugador2"));
personas.add(new Jugador("jugador3"));
personas.add(new Entrenador("entrenador1"));
personas.add(new Entrenador("entrenador2"));

//imprimir jugadores
personas.stream.filter(x->TipoPersona.JUGADOR==x.getTipo()).forEach(System.out::println);

//imprimir entrenadores
personas.stream.filter(x->TipoPersona.ENTRENADOR==x.getTipo()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ojo que esto solo funciona en Java 8 y superiores

Comment: Mala noticia sería no trabajar con Java 8, mínimo, en el 2019 (aunque casos hay).

Comment: No es necesario agregar un atributo que indique el tipo de objeto, es suficiente utilizar un `instanceof`.

Comment: @pablo si supieras las de empresas que trabajan con Java 6 o inferior ....

Comment: @E.Betanzos es mucho mas correcto usar el atributo que el `instance of`

Comment: @JDev sé que existen, pero hay que evitar ponerse en el peor de los casos para dar respuestas con código más o menos moderno

Comment: @JDev me explicas? Porque no estoy de acuerdo para nada. Agregar código en las clases solo para comprobaciones de tipo me parece una pésima práctica.

Comment: @E.Betanzos crea una pregunta sobre ello para poder discutir sobre el tema

Answer (score 0):

Creo que algo así debería de ser.

```
public void consultarJugadores() {
List<clsPersonasClub> jugadores = lista.stream().filter(jugador -> jugador instanceof clsJugadores).collect(Collectors.toList());
for (clsPersonasClub obj :jugadores) {
    clsJugadores jugador = (clsJugadores) obj;
    System.out.println(jugador.toString());
}
```

}

Estoy suponiendo que tus clases de entrenador y jugador extienden a la clase de personal del club.

Y si te recomiendo que sigas las recomendaciones de estilo al poner nombres a las clases y variables.

También he de recomendar que si no usas Java 8 como mínimo lo empieces a hacer.